# Monthwise data in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have small doubt in SQL server. Please tell me how to display month wise data to solve this issue in SQL server.
table data look like below:

Month datatype is `varchar(20)` and id is `int`.

table: months

```
month     |id
April     |1
January   |2
March     |3
Feburary  |4
August    |7
December  |5
May   |6
June      |2
July      |3
August    |NULL
September |2
Octomber  |1
November  |3
June      |8
```

Base on this data I want output like below:

```
month      |id
January    |2
Feburary   |4
March      |3
April      |1
May    |6
June       |2
June       |8
July       |3
August     |NULL
August     |7
September  |2
Octomber   |1
November   |3
December   |5
```

And I've tried like below query:

```
select * 
from  months   
order by datepart(mm,[month]+ ' 01 2010'),id
```

But it show error like:

> msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

Please tell me, how to solve this issue in SQL server?

Comment: Check the month spelling in the all the rows

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you actually using? I sincerely doubt it's all three of 2008, 2008r2 and 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` in `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * 
    FROM YOURTABLE
    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN [month] = 'January' THEN 0             
         WHEN [month] = 'February' THEN 1
         WHEN [month] = 'March' THEN 2
         WHEN [month] = 'April' THEN 3
         WHEN [month] = 'May' THEN 4
         WHEN [month] = 'June' THEN 5
         WHEN [month] = 'July' THEN 6
         WHEN [month] = 'August' THEN 7
         WHEN [month] = 'September' THEN 8
         WHEN [month] = 'October' THEN 9
         WHEN [month] = 'November' THEN 10
         WHEN [month] = 'December' THEN 11
    END
 FROM YOUURTABLE
```

**EDIT :**

Your `February` spelling is wrong.

Comment: thanks,expected output got it ,given query have small syntax error .no need  from tn in the last line.